# PHP doesn't recognise CSV file

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am using a form to upload CSV

```
<form role="form" action="#" method="post" style="color: black;">
            
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

The code to process this to the Database

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] = $_POST) {
    echo $filename=$_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $ext=substr($filename,strrpos($filename,"."),(strlen($filename)-strrpos($filename,".")));
     
    //we check,file must be have csv extention
    if($ext=="csv")
    {
      $file = fopen($filename, "r");
             while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
             {
                $gender = $emapData[2];
                if ($gender = "Male") {
                    $gender = 1;
                } else {
                    $gender = 2;
                }
                $status = $emapData[3];
                if ($status = "Unclaimed") {
                    $status = 1;
                } else {
                    $status = 2;
                }

                $sql = "INSERT into angels(id,age,gender,status,giftername,gifteremail) values('$emapData[0]','$emapData[1]','$gender','$status','$emapData[4]','$emapData[5]')";
                mysqli_query($db_conn, $sql);
             }
             fclose($file);
             echo "CSV File has been successfully Imported.";
    }
    else {
        echo "Error: Please Upload only CSV File";
    }

}
```

?>

I am uploading a .csv file, yet I keep hitting the "Error: Please Upload only CSV File"

Comment: `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] = $_POST) {` You use `==` to check, like in `if($ext=="csv")`  https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: That's a *really* complicated way to calculate a file extension, and it also returns `.csv` rather than `csv`. See https://3v4l.org/KLK0r. You might want to look at [`pathinfo`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) instead. I'm also fairly sure you need to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form.

Comment: As well as the REQUEST_METHOD one, you've also got a single `=` in the gender + status comparisons a bit further down.

Answer (score 0):

You should be checking against ".csv" as your line that grabs the extension copies the dot too. A better way would be to use [pathinfo()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo), and also to make the check case insensitive.

```
<?php

$filename = 'abc.csv';

if (strtolower(pathinfo($filename)['extension']) === 'csv')
{
    // Your csv stuff.
    echo "Doing csv stuff.\n";
}
else
    exit('Error: Please Upload only CSV File');
```

Comment: Hi. I updated this. Now I get 
"Warning: fgetcsv() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/lostfabl/public_html/testsite/cosmos/importcsv.php on line 42" 
Do you know what this could be?

Comment: You need to read `tmp_name`, not `name`. From [the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php): `$_FILES['userfile']['name'] - The original name of the file on the client machine.`

Comment: Also, please update your SQL handling to use prepared statements, your queries are now open to SQL injection.

Comment: You will also need to use the proper `enctype` on the form to handle file uploads. Add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to the `<form>` element.